# Image from asset catalog not accessible

Tags: xcode, asset-catalog

In my project I have multiple asset catalogs, one of which is named `images.xcassets`.
I am able to access all the images inside said asset catalog using either `UIImage(named: "image.png")` or `#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image.png")` (with *and* without the file extension `.png`).

#### Issue

Now, trying to access resource `image2.png` works just fine with the iOS 11.2 iPad 10.5" simulator. However, the exact same build crashes when using the iOS 11.2 iPad 12.9" (2nd gen.) simulator with the following "message":

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

This issue has just emerged, I was always able to access the image before today. I have not touched a thing...

#### What I've tried

- target membership set to project's target
- removed the asset catalog from *Copy Bundle Resources* in *Build Phases*
- cleaned and rebuilt the project
- deleted `image2.png` from the catalog and added it back
- deleted the whole asset catalog and added it back
- deleted the app from the 12.9" simulator and re-installed it
- quit & re-opened Xcode and the simulator

Any idea why this specific resource can't be accessed anymore?

---

Notes:

- so far, I didn't run into this error using real devices (tested with iPad Air 2 & iPad Pro 1st Gen.)

Comment: check target membership.

Comment: As stated in my post, I have already done that. Also, I wouldn't be able to access any other images from the catalog if the target wasn't set.

Answer (score 0):

[Has to do with the color space apparently](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80389).

I was able to "save for web" in Photoshop and convert the image to sRGB for an image file that doesn't crash in the iPad Pro 12.9" 2nd generation simulator.